# Probability of sample mean

Tags: r, distributions, normal-distribution, mean

Consider independent random variables  $Z_{i}\sim N(0,1),\;i=1,\ldots,16$
and let  $\bar{Z}$  be the sample mean. Then calculate  $P\left[Z_1-Z_2<2\right]$

This is an example of one of the questions I'm trying to do, there's also similar ones of trying to find Z1+Z2 and trying to find the probability the sample mean is greater/less than a certain value. I've looked in my notes and i can't find anything similar to this so any help would be appreciated. I'm not looking for the exact answer just some hints on how to get it myself. Thanks

Comment: For  hints, [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+self-study+probability).

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the samples are normally distributed, which is fair.

For same distribution of both RV, and $P\left[Z_1-Z_2<2\right]$ you calculate the mean and std.

$μ_D=μ_1−μ_2$ and $σ_D^2=σ_1^2+σ_2^2$

And `pnorm` gives the CDF function

```
pnorm(2, mean=0, sd=1.4142)
```

Comment: Thanks for that but how would i calculate the mean/sd for each of them if this is all the info i am given? Is it mean of 0 and sd of 1 for both?

Comment: Yes for both of them the mean is 0 and sd is 1, and for Z1-Z1 the mean is 0 and the sd is sqrt(2)

Comment: sorry was there something else at the end, sqrt(2) - what?

Comment: sqrt(2) is just √ 2

Comment: – (m-dash) is just a feature of this site comments.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help just one last thing, would 16 not be used in the calculations at all? It seems odd that this number would given if it is not needed in the question?

Comment: @EasyPoints: Good answer. But note that with $Z_1$ ~ $N(0,1)$ and $Z_2$ ~ $N(0,1)$ and independent, you can conclude that ($Z_1-Z_2$)~$N(0,\sqrt2)$. Your statement "If you assume the samples are normally distributed..." is unclear to me.

Comment: @ColorStatistics so would you do this question a different way?

Comment: @MikeHunt: No. I am just pointing out that sampling doesn't figure here in any way. It is unclear to me why you'd be provided with details such as $i=1,2,...,16$. Either your professor wants to emphasize certain things, or this is a red herring. You are working here with the entire distribution of these random variables and not with crystalized values of these/samples.

Comment: @ColorStatistics $P\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{16}Z_i^2<32\right]  $   is one of the later parts of the question so perhaps that is why i am given it?

Comment: @ColorStatistics I am having hard time to reason after your question, but you may assume the t-student distribution on of samples, right? This is an option sampling procedure brings.

Comment: @EasyPoints: Trying to understand your point. Why do you need to assume anything in this question? $Z_1,Z_2,(Z_1-Z_2)$ are all random variables, which means they can take on a certain set of values with a certain probability distribution. The question $P(Z_1-Z_2<2)$ asks what is the probability that this random variable $(Z_1-Z_2)$ will take a value less than 2. If you know the mean and standard deviation for a normally distributed random variable, you know its entire CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function) and should be able to compute the value of CDF at 2. No assumptions made about sampling.

Comment: @ColorStatistics I missed your comment, the thing is that the normal distribution is not accurate when the sample size is small, and since we don't know the sample size and we have the indication that we are sampling I said this extra comment. What I said my not be true, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @EasyPoints: I think you are thinking this question is somehow about Inference. It is not. This is a probability question. There is no inference here from a sample to a population. You know the probability distribution here and you are asked to find the probability of an event. That's all.

Comment: OK, I will improve my notes than. I still don't get it quite, but I will use your brain in here :) and probable understand it tomorrow.